# Scrollview on a gridlayout inside a relativelayout with static floating action button

Tags: android, android-scrollview, floating-action-button, android-gridlayout

Have been playing around trying to find a solution for my problem. I have a gridlayout inside a relativelayout (center) and a floating action button. I only want the gridlayout to scroll , and have tried multiple solutions from stackoverflow.

The obvious would be to put a scrollview on the gridlayout itself, but this makes all alignments off. Unless i am missing something here? Code below is without scrollview and how it should look.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/settings"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/innstillinger"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/database"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:hint="@string/database"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColorHint="#3293a8"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/server"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:hint="@string/server"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColorHint="#3293a8"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:hint="@string/port"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColorHint="#3293a8"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:autofillHints="Passord"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:hint="@string/brukernavn"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColorHint="#3293a8"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:autofillHints="Passord"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:hint="@string/passord"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColorHint="#3293a8"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/connectbutton"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/koble_til"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="Automatisk backup "
        android:textColor="@color/settings"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/soundButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/scannelyd"
        android:textColor="@color/settings"

        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/om_hip_vareteller"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/settings"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</GridLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnTilbakeK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="tilbakeKameraKnapp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/update"
    android:text="kamera" />
```

Comment: For some reason the end tag is not in the codeblock, even though it shows in editor here.

Answer (score 1):

Only changed Gridlayout and put it inside the scrollview like this to maintain the same margins;

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/innstillinger"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:rowCount="1">
```